# using clearfix from bootstrap on paragraph and link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to clear a floated link in a paragraph. I set the clearfix to the root div which contains the floated element and the normal elements.

```
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Accountoverview</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
          Test
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mnlfischer/gv98D/3/

on the viewport size 800px the link (button) breaks the structure.

Is there a way to fix it?

Full Size Resolution:
http://jsfiddle.net/mnlfischer/gv98D/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a clearfix to the parent p tag. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8aGC6/

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <p class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Test</a>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The clearfix needs to go on the immediate parent element of the floated elements which is why your solution does not work, and this one by Mozammil does.